# How can I use handlebars-helpers in browser with normal handlebarsjs?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I just start using handlebarsjs and found out about handlebars-helpers: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers

But I'm not sure how to get this working in a browser. The examples seem to be for use in a gulp file. I also notice it does have an area for getting it to work in browser: https://github.com/doowb/handlebars-helpers-browserify-example, and going to the working demo I see the generated js it talks about creating: https://doowb.com/handlebars-helpers-browserify-example/app.js so I tried just adding that to my js references after handlebars:

```
<script src="~/lib/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://doowb.com/handlebars-helpers-browserify-example/app.js"></script>
```

But in my template when I try and reference add `{{add @index + 1}}`. I get missing helper add error in console. And here is my template code:

```
        var source = $("#questions-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        var questionData = JSON.parse('{ "questions":data }');
        var html = template(questionData);
        $("#questions-template-output").html(html);
```

I am pretty new to gulp and other pre/post processing stuff. I feel like I am missing something obvious. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: I don't mean to ignore your question and sound like I'm smarter than you. I had a similar issue and a co-worker suggested I use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and that was WAY better than using 3rd party templating. Maybe it'll work for your project?

Comment: Does that work for handlebarsjs? I see no mention of being able to do what you linked in the documentation: http://handlebarsjs.com/#literals. Can you provide an example of how you would use that to show the `index + 1` inside a loop within a template??

Comment: What I'm suggesting is a paradigm shift for your project, completely away from handlebars and towards vanilla JS with HTML. Google `template literals vs handlebars` and read if you're interested. I've gotta run but will come back later tonight and provide more info if someone else hasn't already.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I'm suggesting. Run this in the chrome console or jsfiddle.

```
let element = document.createElement('div')
let randomArray = ['help', 'chocolate', 'eagle'];
let name = window.prompt("What's your name?", "World");
// remove the .join() below and see what happens :)
element.innerHTML = `
  <h1>Hi, ${name}! This element is looping</h1>
  ${randomArray.map((item, i) => `
    <div>I am ${item}, item number ${i}</div>
  `).join('')}
`
document.body.append(element);
```

You might not want to change your project at this point, but it is probably a good idea to at least slowly move from Handlebars to JavaScript's template literals. Handlebars has a lot of limitations which you're going to continue running into, and you'll need to mess with helpers which you've already seen aren't straightforward. However, this code is all JS and HTML, which you already know.

For more info, there's [Wes Bos' blog](https://wesbos.com/template-strings-html/), the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and [this random gist](https://gist.github.com/wiledal/3c5b63887cc8a010a330b89aacff2f2e).

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea due to browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. IE doesn't support them at all and most browsers also don't support escape sequences in them.

Comment: @SventoryMang I agree with you, I tried to be clear that this isn't a 100% do it and never consider anything else, but it depends on what kind of browser support you need. Either way I think it's going to be more and more common, while template engines fade like jQuery (ie not completely, but there will be a move away from it), so being familiar with it is helpful.